# React Native ReactContext lifecycle stuck on BEFORE_CREATE

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to run a background service in React-Native. From what I've heard I need to write it in native Java and connect it to the react-native code. When I try to emit an event I get an error:

```
Tried to access a JS module before the React instance was fully set up. Calls to should only happen once initialize() has been called on your native module.
```

So I added a check to see if the Module is running:

```
if (reactContext.getLifecycleState() == LifecycleState.RESUMED)
```

But it always returns false. The lifecycle is stuck on BEFORE_CREATE. How should I emit my event.

Service:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

double distance = 0.0;
ReactContext reactContext;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    reactContext = new ReactContext(getApplicationContext());
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            distance+= 0.7;
            Log.d("LOG", "Trying to send distance: "+distance+" on lifecycle: "+reactContext.getLifecycleState());
            params.putDouble("distance", distance);
            sendEvent(reactContext, "updateDistance", params);
        }
    },0,1000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    if (reactContext.getLifecycleState() == LifecycleState.RESUMED) {
        reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule
                .RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
        Log.d("LOG", "Sent distance: "+distance);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Module:

```
public class ServiceModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
ReactContext reactContext;

public ServiceModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
    this.initialize();
}

@ReactMethod
public void startTrackingService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(reactContext, TestService.class);
    reactContext.startService(intent);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "ServiceModule";
}
}
```

Package:

```
public class ServicePackage implements ReactPackage {
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.add(new ServiceModule(reactContext));
    return modules;
}

@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
}
```

MainApplication:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new ReactNativePushNotificationPackage(),
      new ServicePackage()
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it :)
In the service I was creating a new context from base context which is NOT the same object. The workaround was to broadcast the data from the service and then send them do javascript.

ServiceModule:

```
public class ServiceModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
public static String UPDATE = "updateDistance";
public static String DISTANCE = "distance";

private IntentFilter intentFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

public ServiceModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    initializeBroadcastReceiver();
}

@ReactMethod
public void startTrackingService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(), TestService.class);
    getReactApplicationContext().startService(intent);
}

@ReactMethod
public void stopTrackingService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(), TestService.class);
    getReactApplicationContext().stopService(intent);
}

private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
        reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
    }
}

private void initializeBroadcastReceiver() {
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(UPDATE);
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putDouble(DISTANCE, intent.getDoubleExtra(DISTANCE, 0));
            sendEvent(getReactApplicationContext(), UPDATE, params);
        }
    };
    getReactApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "ServiceModule";
}
}
```

TestService:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

double distance = 0.0;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction(ServiceModule.UPDATE);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra(ServiceModule.DISTANCE, distance);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            distance+= 0.7;
        }
    },0,1000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Was it the `if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance())` in `sendEvent` that did it? That's what fixed a similar error on my end. That said, I had no guard at all when I received the error, whereas your original had `if (reactContext.getLifecycleState() == LifecycleState.RESUMED)`

Comment: reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance() has been deprecated, I used hasActiveReactInstance() instead.